# Is it necessary to logout of SSH?

Tags: ssh

If files are being edited, I know .swp can be left, and also the history of commands is not written, but are there any serious drawbacks to just terminating the shell rather than exiting cleanly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the security view nothing at all. It's just a question of connection. If something goes wrong there can be a non aligned connection between client and server, in which one think the other is connected but in fact it's not. In that case you have to wait for the timeout. From what I know you can force the client to exit with

```
ENTER ~ .
```

but server side I think you'll just have to wait.

However normally, the closing of the client shell is heard by the server.